# Msbuild epi server project modules missing

Tags: .net, msbuild, msbuild-task, episerver

Trying to make an automation for epi server .net development.
The msbuild is running good but for some reason in the build folder it missing the modules folder . Tried addmodules flag for msbuild , did not work . 
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not included in the `.csproj` file. You need to copy the `modules` folder manually or modify your build target to include additional files.

Simplest way is to click "Show all files" in Solution Explorer in VS and then include the `modules` folder in your project. Make sure the Build Action for all files is "Content". The folder will then be included when building/publishing.

Alternatively you can modify your `.csproj` file to include additional files when publishing: https://ajmburns.wordpress.com/2016/04/10/including-additional-generated-files-when-publishing-a-net-web-application/